# Concatenate variable with $$ in PHP

Tags: php

I have this declaration:

```
$arr = 'Banana';
```

How can I use `Banana` in my new variable ?

```
$fruitBanana = 'Content';
```

What I've tried:

```
$fruit$$arr = 'Content';
echo $fruit$$arr; // Should echo 'Content'
```

But it was not working.

Comment: I think you're confusing concatenation with variable variables, it's quite hard to make sense of what you want.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? https://3v4l.org/VEdNn

Comment: This is pretty dirty. Don't follow such approaches.

Comment: There might be some cases where this syntax is useful, but I haven't come across a practical situation where you would use this over something like `$fruits = ['Banana' => 'Content']`, then `$index = 'Banana';`, then finally `$fruits[$index]`, or similar. It's neat that you can do this, and makes for some fun programming exercises, like `$one = 'two';`, `$two = 'one';`, then `$$$$$$$one` being perfectly valid, but yeah... There are usually better, cleaner and clearer approaches available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are variable variables, not concatenation.

The correct code would be:

```
$arr = 'Banana';
$fruitBanana = 'Content'; // OR $fruit{$arr} = 'Content';

echo ${"fruit{$arr}"};
// 'Content'
```

Reminder, concatenation is done via the `.` operator.